# Vue component doesn't raise error but not renders anything

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to make [vue-google-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-autocomplete) work on my website. Since it's a `Django` project and I don't use `nmp` nor I know how to use that, I'm trying to use [http-vue-loader](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/http-vue-loader).

The problem is that I can't see anything except `VUE works` on the website.

**JSFIDDLE**

> https://jsfiddle.net/zwjs8k75/7/

**JS**

```
Vue.use(httpVueLoader);
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    'testmessage': 'VUE works'
  },
  'components': {
    'vue-google-autocomplete': 'url:https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-google-autocomplete@1.1.0/src/VueGoogleAutocomplete.vue'
  },


  methods: {
    /**
     * When the location found
     * @param {Object} addressData Data of the found location
     * @param {Object} placeResultData PlaceResult object
     * @param {String} id Input container ID
     */
    getAddressData: function(addressData, placeResultData, id) {
      this.address = addressData;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I think you are not passing your api key in the html it might be because of that?

Comment: You have not used the right api key for google map

Comment: Sorry guys I didn't metion it, of course I'm using good api key but I didn't want to show it. And moreover I think it would raise some error.

Comment: I think you are not registering your component ok

Comment: @Loki So how should I register it?